# How to prove that the integral below in independent of $\theta$ and $\phi$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, spherical-coordinates

Consider the following triple integral:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \int_0^1
\frac{1}{h} \frac{1-\alpha Q^2}{1 + \alpha Q^2 (1-\alpha Q^2)} \frac{\sin \vartheta}{\sqrt{1-Q^2}} \, \mathrm{d}Q \, \mathrm{d}\vartheta\, \mathrm{d} \varphi \, , 
$$
where
$$
h^2 = 2a^2 \left( 1-\sin\theta \sin\vartheta \cos(\phi-\varphi)-\cos\theta\cos\vartheta \right) \, , 
$$
and 
$$
\alpha = \left(\frac{a}{h}\right)^2 
\left[ \sin^2\theta+\sin^2\vartheta-2 \sin\theta \sin\vartheta \cos(\phi-\varphi) \right] \, .
$$
Here, $a$ is a strictly positive real number (particle radius).

Actually, the integral quantifies a certain physical quantity that is supposed to be *constant* at the surface of the sphere.
Therefore, the integral is expected to be independent of $\theta$ and $\phi$ which represent the polar and azimuthal angles, respectively. 
Numerically, this can be checked but I was wondering whether there exists analytical techniques that can be used to show that in a rigorous way.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Hartmut Helmut

Comment: @L.G. Q is an integration variable between 0 and 1. I will rewrite the integral

Comment: If you know what this integral means physically and how it is constructed does that not tell you why it is independent of the two variables?

Comment: @Paul In fact, the integral is supposed to be so but still this needs to be proved. Thanks

Comment: No need for proof. $h,\alpha$ are constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be your integral. Since you are not integrating over $\theta, \phi$, the easiest way to show this is to show that

$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial I}{\partial \phi} = 0. $$

Since your variables of integration are $\vartheta, \varphi$ and $Q$, you can just pull both derivatives inside of the integral, so that you don't have to do any integration at all. If indeed your integral is independent of $\theta, \phi$, this should be quite simple.